# Could not determine GDB version after sending: arm-none-eabi-gdb --version, response:

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, ubuntu-14.04, arm7

I'm trying to debug a project on Kinetis Design Studio with GDB PEMicro Interface Debugging but I get this error: **'Launching myProject' has encountered a problem. Could not determine GDB version after sending: arm-none-eabi-gdb --version, response:**

I formatted my computer there is a few days. And a had other computer to the same settings and it worked well.

My settings:

**Eclipse Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Global Tools Paths**

- Build tools folder: (empty)
- Default toolchain: GNU Tools for ARM Embedded
- Toolchain folder: /opt/Freescale/KDS_v3/toolchain/bin

**Eclipse Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Workspace Tools Paths**

- Build tools folder: empty
- Default toolchain: Global default
- Toolchain folder: empty

**Project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tools Paths**

- empty

**Project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Toolchains**

- Name: GNU Tools for ARM Embedded
- Architecture: ARM
- Prefix: arm-none-eabi-
- Suffix: (empty)
- Toolchain path: /opt/Freescale/KDS_v3/toolchain/bin

**Project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Environment -> PATH**

- Origin: BUILD SYSTEM

**Debug launch configuration -> Main tab**

- Project: myProject
- C/C++ Application: myProject/myProject.elf

**Debug launch configuration -> Debugger tab**

- GDB Client Settings -> Executable: ${cross_prefix}gdb${cross_suffix}
- Commands:

> set mem inaccessible-by-default off
>
> set tcp auto-retry on
>
> set tcp connect-timeout 240

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried running `arm-none-eabi-gdb --version` on a console to see what happens ? (you have to have the command in the path of course)

Comment: I can't to type on console eclipse if debug isn't running. And in the linux console I can't to running that command because GDB isn't installed "directly" on linux cause' it comes with kinetis, and it is not necessary to be installed. I check it in other computer that GDB is working and the GDB wasn't installed, i.e, the command `arm-none-eabi-gdb --version` is not recognized.

Answer (score 14):

I had a help of a coworker. We tried to run the gdb on terminal (`./arm-none-eabi-gdb`) in its directory `/opt/Freescale/KDS_v3/toolchain/bin` and it returns:

./arm-none-eabi-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So I solved it with this command on terminal:

`sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386`

Probably this error occurs due the architecture of my machines that is x64 and the architecture of the arm-none-eabi-gdb is x86. And some times some dependencies of linux can to change this libs. So in some machines it can to work but in other not.

Answer (score 4):

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 x64. 
On my system `libncruses5` is already installed.
Eclipse (KDS) + Segger.
When trying to bring up the debugger, error `Could not determine GDB version after sending: arm-none-eabi-gdb --version, response:` is shown.

```
     sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386
```

The 32-bit version of `libncurses5` is needed.
Once it is in place, problem is resolved.